# SQL: Add a column and classify into categories

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a table which has `transaction_id` as the primary key and also contains `customer_id` which is a foreign key.

Now there is a column `type` which has two values: `'Card'` and `'cash'`.

Now some of the customers have used both the methods for payment. I want to add a new column and classify the customers as "Only card" "Only cash" and "Both".

```
Transaction id      Customer id Type
1                   100         Card   
2                   101         Cash 
3                   102         Card 
4                   103         Cash
5                   101         Card
```

So in this table I want a new column 'Type of payment' which classifies customer 101 as Both since he has used both the methods of payment.

Comment: Would that value not only be valid at the point in time you ran it? what if they paid via another method later? Would it not be better to pull that value via a query as and when needed?

Comment: Yes I agree that value would be valid only upto a point of time. But I want to analyze the payment method till now. I am looking for the best method. If adding a new column isn't the best way, please suggest how can I do it otherwise without having to add a column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than adding a column to the table, if what you want to do is analyze the payment methods, then doing something like this might be better:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Table1.[Customer ID], T1.*
FROM Table1
CROSS APPLY (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Cash' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Cash,
           SUM(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Card' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Card
          FROM Table1 T WHERE T.[Customer ID] = Table1.[Customer ID]) T1
```

Gives you results like this:

```
CUSTOMER ID CASH    CARD
100          0       1
101          1       1
102          0       1
103          1       0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when min(type) over (partition by customerid) = max(type) over (partition by customerid)
             then 'Only ' + min(type) over (partition by customerid)
             else 'both'
        end)
from transactions t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do better and remove a bit of redondancy (the values cash only and card only will be repeated in the table, in this case we prefer repeating an ID). So you can create a Table for example `payement_methods` that will have 2 columns for example `id` and `method`, you will populate it with the three options you just mentioned (cash only, card only, both), and you'll have in your `transaction table` a column `payment_method_id` for example (instead of the type column you were using).

example

```
|id     | method       |
|1      | Cash only    |
|2      | Card Only    |
|3      | Both         |
```

transaction table

```
|id     | other columns ...|payement method  |
|1      | other columns ...|1                |
|2      | other columns ...|3                |
//...
```

sorry for my english, good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
Create table tran1(Transactionid int ,   Customerid int  , Type varchar(100))

insert into tran1(Transactionid ,   Customerid , Type ) values
(1         ,          100    ,     'Card ' ),
(2         ,          101    ,     'Cash' ),
(3         ,          102    ,     'Card ' ),
(4         ,          103    ,     'Cash ' ),
(5         ,          101    ,     'Card ' )

alter table tran1 add NewType varchar(100)



Update tran1 set NewType ='Only card' where Customerid IN  (
select d.custid from (
 select Customerid as custid,SUM(case when [Type]='Card' then 1 else 0 end) card
 ,SUM(case when [Type]='Cash' then 1 else 0 end) cash
 from tran1
 group by Customerid)d
 where d.card=1  
 )


Update tran1 set NewType ='Only Cash' where Customerid IN  (
select d.custid from (
 select Customerid as custid,SUM(case when [Type]='Card' then 1 else 0 end) card
 ,SUM(case when [Type]='Cash' then 1 else 0 end) cash
 from tran1
 group by Customerid)d
 where d.cash=1  
 )

Update tran1 set NewType ='Both' where Customerid IN  (
select d.custid from (
 select Customerid as custid,SUM(case when [Type]='Card' then 1 else 0 end) card
 ,SUM(case when [Type]='Cash' then 1 else 0 end) cash
 from tran1
 group by Customerid)d
 where d.card=1 and cash=1
 )
```